# Excel VBA Copy a Range into a New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie to `Excel VBA`.

I am trying to copy a range of data from worksheet output into a new excel workbook and save the new workbook with the the value in E3.

As a bonus, I would love to be able to also copy the data into `wordpad` and save as E3.xml

Here is the `VBA` I have thus far:

```
Sub CopyOutput()
Dim myname As String
mystring = E3
Dim myselection As Range

myselection = Sheets("Output").Columns("F").Select
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Program Files\White Plume\Scenarios\" & myname & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
             xlsx, CreateBackup:=False
    End With
myselection.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire `column F` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modify to suit your specifics, or make more generic as needed:

```
Private Sub CopyItOver()
  Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
  Workbooks("Whatever.xlsx").Worksheets("output").Range("A1:K10").Copy
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  NewBook.SaveAs FileName:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Lance.  The script for the copy and paste works, but I am still having a problem with the SaveAs.  I am trying to create the file named A3.xlsx  My VBA line is below:  NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value

Comment: You need to be much more specific with what your problem is?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Note that if you just can't find the file, mine ended up in the Documents folder.  You will probably want to specify the path also.

Comment: The file is saving in the correct path, but it is saving as a 01 File instead of .xlsx

Comment: I'm away from my machine now to see what mine saved as extension-wise, but you could just try concatenating the extension on, Range("A3").value & ".xlsx"

Comment: Lance how can i copy certain columns from the active sheet?

Comment: @vignesh, just change the Range, like ...Range("A:B").Copy