# In Excel macro how can I accept a user's choice of column?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel macro, how can I accept a user's choice of column, then copy that column to a new excel sheet and then repeat the proccess for a number of columns (say 7)?

Edit:

using brettdj's answer combined with the link provided by pasty I got this, which did the job:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim NewBook As Workbook


Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select a column", "User selection - entire column will be copied", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

rng1.EntireColumn.Copy NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1]


End If
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Copy a Range into a New Workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook)

Comment: Maybe this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook) can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.InputBox`, something like this

```
Sub TrySomethingNextTime()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select a column", "User selection - entire column will be copied", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
On Error Goto 0

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    rng1.EntireColumn.Copy ws.[a1]
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[brettdj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641067/brettdj) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21510433/5292302) adapted for rows:

```
Sub TrySomethingNextTime2()
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select a row", "User selection -    entire row will be copied", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
     Set ws = Sheets.Add
     rng1.EntireRow.Copy ws.[a1]
  End If

 End Sub
```