# How to break up excel spreadsheet into separate excel sheets separated by rows

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have an excel spreadsheet with about 10,000 records and about 8 columns.  I would like to break up the excel spreadsheet into different spreadsheets containing data from 250 rows each.  So for example. 
Spread sheet 1 would have 250 rows
Spread sheet 2 would have another 250 rows (251-500 from the original 10,000 list) and so on so forth until it's all completed.  It should also retain the original header on each spreadsheet.

Any one can help?

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work assuming data from A1:Z1000. Just change the range, workbook name and "save as" path as needed.

```
Sub generateSheets()

Dim sheetName As String
Dim headerRng As Range


Set headerRng = Workbooks("GenerateSheetsTest.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 0 To 1000 Step 250
sheetName = "Until" & i + 250
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
headerRng.Copy
NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Workbooks("GenerateSheetsTest.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i + 2 & ":Z" & i + 251).Copy
NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
NewBook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Documents\Output\" & sheetName & ".xlsx"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.