# Copy columns to new workbook and save as csv

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to:

- Copy data (columns A and B) from one workbook (data.xlsx).
- Paste into a new workbook (as values).
- Save as CSV with a filename taken from column A in a third workbook (URLs.xlsx).
- Process to repeat, taking the same data (which is randomised every time it is pasted) from data.xlsx and pasted into a new CSV - there are 200 rows in URLs.xlsx and so we should end up with 200 files.

I've read lots of topics, here are two I found:

[Excel VBA Copy a Range into a New Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook)
https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/

**What I've tried**

Copying code and replacing the relevant components from various different articles across the web. Some of them work, but when I add the missing bits, I run into errors I don't understand.

Comment: how is the data randomised every time it is pasted?

Comment: The data.xlsx file has some =RANDBETWEEN function in it to randomise numbers for columns A and B. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for your response. When I've tried doing this manually, each time I paste into the new workbook it automatically refreshes the random number generation in the data.xlsx file. Will this not continue to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is an example avoiding copy pasting in new workbooks:

Expected input like:

Data.xlsx range `A1:B200` with `RANDBETWEEN()` function:

[image]

URLs.xlsx range `A1:A200` with some URL like so:

[image]

Run this code (will take approximately 1 second on my machine, tested with timer):

```
Dim wbData As Workbook, WBurls As Workbook
Dim CSVFileDir As String, CSVVal As String
Dim A As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, Z As Long

Option Explicit

Sub Transfer2CSV()

Set wbData = Workbooks("data.xlsx") 'Make sure it is open upon running macro
Set WBurls = Workbooks("URLs.xlsx") 'Make sure it is open upon running macro

For X = 1 To 200 'Looping through the 200 rows of WBurls
    CSVFileDir = "C:\YourDrive\" & WBurls.Sheets(1).Cells(X, 1).Value & ".csv"
    CSVVal = ""
    A = FreeFile
    Open CSVFileDir For Output As #A
    With wbData.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B200") ' or whichever range you using here
        .Calculate 'Randomize your range again
        For Y = 1 To 200 'or however many rows you have in column A and B.
            For Z = 1 To 2
                CSVVal = CSVVal & .Cells(Y, Z).Value & ","
            Next Z
            Print #A, Left(CSVVal, Len(CSVVal) - 2)
            CSVVal = ""
        Next Y
    End With
    Close #A
Next X

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

With each file looking like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much JvdV - I can see that it is creating the files as required and that they are populated with data. However, there is an issue with it, so will spend some time reviewing it to see if I can figure it out myself. Thanks again - really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tjm92, what is the issue?

Comment: This solution creates 200 documents correctly, however the data within the documents is in a single row running horizontally. The data within the data.xlsx file is 2 columns and 200 rows. Everything else using this code seems to have worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Tjm92, I can't reproduce that mishap, in fact, i re-ran everything and output was as expected. Please check if the data setup is the same.

Comment: @JvdV, are Columns A & B concatenated in your output files; it seems like column B is empty

Comment: @JvdV, I get that. But in excel, they should open as columns. Why not save using the xlCSV format?

Comment: No, it works fine, my own pc uses `;` as delimiter per standard @AAA. If I would change the comma to a semicolon in the code I can open the `.CSV` files just fine with both column A and B populated. Sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: Thank you JvdV, just tested this code and it's working perfectly now. All of the files have populated as required. Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Make sure your data and URLS workbooks are open.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsUrl As Worksheet, wbNew as Workbook
Dim CSVDir as String, rngU As Range

Set wsData = Workbooks("data.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
Set wsUrl = Workbooks("URLs.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
Set rngU = wsUrl.Range("A1", wsUrl.Range("A" & wsUrl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
CSVDir = "C:\Users\thomas.mcerlean\Desktop\Work\" 'you gave this as your dir
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

For Each cell In rngU
    wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Range("B" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:= wbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:= CSVDir & cell.Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Next cell

wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment here AAA, appreciate it! I've plugged in the following for the drive location: CSVDir = "Drive:C:\Users\thomas.mcerlean\Desktop\Work\" and when I step through this via F8 it gives me the following error: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. The row before this opens up a blank document. Is this something I've done incorrectly?

Comment: I used Drive to indicate your drive letter. This might be C or some other letter. In your case it is C. So, set  CSVDir = "C:\Users\thomas.mcerlean\Desktop\Work\"

Comment: I have modified the answer and tried it. It works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you SO much - is there any way I can rate you on here, or is it just via up votes? This worked perfectly and you have saved me an ---awful--- long time. Very happy right now - thanks!

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed that the random number generation bit didn't work - as you said in your original comments. :-(

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I managed to get this functioning using the code  from Jvdv below. Really appreciate it you looking into this for me! :-)