# How to apply Worksheets.SaveAs function?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am working on a script to export a range from my basesheet to a specific worksheet. (The names for the worksheets are checked and created with a while loop. If the name is already there, the content will be cleared and repasted.)

The last step is saving a range to a .txt file, but it gives

> 'Run-time error '1004'
> Application-defined or object-defined' error

I searched for similar error but those couldn't fix it.

#UPDATE

I updated my code to show the changes after the suggestions made in the comments.

I get

> Run-time error '438'
> Object doesn't support this property or method

```vb
Option Explicit ' Force explicit variable declaration.

Sub test_wh()    
    Dim exportFolder As String
    Dim filedialog As filedialog
    Dim fd
   
    Set fd = Application.filedialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With fd
        .Title = "Select folder for export wh and wg files"
        If .Show = True Then
            exportFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
     '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    Dim nameSheet As String
    Dim baseSheet As String: baseSheet = "BASE"
    Dim actSheet As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As String
        
    actSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    i = 30
    f = 0

    Do While i < 361
        x = "wh" & i

        If Len(nameSheet) < 5 Then
            nameSheet = "wh0" & i
        End If

        If DoesSheetExists(nameSheet) Then
            Worksheets(nameSheet).range("A1:B27").ClearContents
            Worksheets(baseSheet).range("AP22").Offset(f, 0).Resize(27, 1).Copy
            Worksheets(nameSheet).range("A1:A27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Worksheets(baseSheet).range("AQ22").Offset(f, 0).Resize(27, 1).Copy
            Worksheets(nameSheet).range("B1:B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("actSheet")).Name = nameSheet
            Worksheets(baseSheet).range("AP22").Offset(f, 0).Resize(27, 1).Copy
            Worksheets(nameSheet).range("A1:A27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Worksheets(baseSheet).range("AQ22").Offset(f, 0).Resize(27, 1).Copy
            Worksheets(nameSheet).range("B1:B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

        '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim lCell As String
        Dim foldername As String
    
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        lCell = "B" & lRow
        foldername = exportFolder & "\" & nameSheet & ".txt"

        Worksheets(nameSheet).range("A1:" & lCell).SaveAs Filename:=foldername, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

        Sheets(nameSheet).Activate
        i = i + 30
        f = f + 1
    Loop

    'Call wg_test
End Sub
```

Comment: `Filenaam` should be `FileName` and `.Range("A1:lCell")` should be `.Range("A1:" & lCell)`. And `foldername` is probably missing some file extension `foldername = exportFolder & "\" & nameSheet & ".txt"`

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of modules (or just check "Require Variable Declarations" in Tools-Options) and compiling VBA project (under Debug menu) will help you catch these easier.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for responding. I tried your suggestions but it still causes an error. I now have this code to save the worksheets

' Worksheets(nameSheet).SaveAs Filename:=foldername, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False'

Comment: Ok since you changed the code to something else please [edit] your question and show your actual code. Also *"an error"* is not helpful we need to know **which** error massage you get. Did you add `Option Explicit` as suggested above? • Also note that `Sheets(nameSheet).Active` is no valid syntax and should be `Sheets(nameSheet).Activate`

Comment: Ah ok, the issue is  that a `Range` does not have a `.SaveAs` method. You can only use `.SaveAs` with an entire worksheet or a workbook (not with a range). If you want to save a range in a new workbook then you need to copy it to a new workbook first: Therefore see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325865/excel-vba-copy-a-range-into-a-new-workbook).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by activating the preferred worksheet and then saving the active workbook. These lines were added:

```
Worksheets(nameSheet).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=foldername, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: You should be abele to save the worksheet directly `Worksheets(nameSheet).SaveAs …` which is better than using `.Activate`.

Comment: The problem lies in the `FileFormat:=xlText`, this should be `FileFormat:=xlTextWindows`. Found it when i wanted to save it as a CSV file.